# iOS EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access

My application was working fine, and a couple minutes later, after editing another part of the app, it started throwing the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error from a view controller that I wasn't even working on. The only thing I did between that I can think that may have affected it is, I Edit->Refractor->Convert to Obj-C ARC... I only did it it for a specified file also, not my whole project which is confusing. I was following this tutorial when I believe the error started happening... http://sonnyparlin.com/2011/12/pulltorefresh-ios-5-and-arc-tutorial/
Also, the app launches fine, it just crashes when a cell is clicked on in the tableview. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Error happens on this line:**

```
self.releaselink = [[sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"link"];
```

**Here's my code where the error is originating from:**

```
@implementation PressReleaseViewController

@synthesize releaselink;

UILabel *departmentNamesLabel;
CGRect *departmentNamesFrame;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

// Load path to plist and sort based on "name"

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                  @"departments" ofType:@"plist"];
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
}

// How many sections are in the table

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

// Set how many rows of cells are in the table

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [sortedArray count];
}

// Set up table view and format for cells

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell* cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];

// Set text for each cell

cell.textLabel.text = [[sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];

return cell;
}

// Set how tall each cell is

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return 40;
}

// Set push to new view controller

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

self.releaselink = [[sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"link"];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle: nil];
MainViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"main"];
[vc setReleaseLink:self.releaselink];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
pressReleases = nil;
[super viewDidUnload];
}
@end
```

Header file"

```
@interface PressReleaseViewController : UITableViewController {

IBOutlet UITableView *pressReleases;
NSArray *array;
NSArray *sortedArray;
NSString *releaselink;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *releaselink;

@end
```

Comment: What specifically does the crash report say?

Comment: Where did you declare `sortedArray`?

Comment: Please post the .h file as well

Comment: sortedArray is declared in the header file as NSArray *sortedArray; and the error is (code=2, address=0x9)

Comment: header file has been added...

Comment: What are you storing in your sortedArray?

Comment: it reads from a plist where I have multiple dictionaries with two strings under each, "name" and "link"

Comment: Have you enabled Zombies by going to `Product` -> `Edit Scheme` and selecting `Enable Zombie Objects`.

Comment: how do you copy a plist to post?

Comment: I just enabled it and now I get a EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors occur when your application attempts to access an object that has already been released. If the issue happened after you converted the project to ARC, then somewhere there is a Zealous release call being made (on behalf of ARC). Try making `sortedArray` a **strong** property of your class, and set the variable as :

```
self.sortedArray = [array sortUsingDescriptor:...];
```

That must be it, because `sortUsingDescriptor:` probably returns an autoreleased object. In a non-arc project you'd have to encapsulate that call with a retain call:

```
[[array sortUsingDescriptor:...]retain];
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much. I have looked through the class that I converted to ARC and I can't find anything getting released that would screw it up. So weird...

Comment: It's not this class? The autorelease pool triggers after each run cycle (I believe), so the tableView refreshing happens on one cycle. When you tap an object in the table, the memory is freed.  Hope this still works later down the line

Comment: Yeah it was the PullDownRefresh tutorial I was mentioning above that I converted and the error happened after that. Not to mention, I was using that pull down refresh on a totally different table than this one too.